# How to fetch current GMT value?

Tags: android, timezone

In my app, I am using GeoNamesAPI for fetching the current time at any location.
I have registered for using that.

My code looks like:

```
Timezone currentTimeZone;
org.geonames.WebService.setUserName("mathew");
currentTimeZone = GeoNamesAPI.fetchTimeZone(latitude, longitude);
```

The problem is when I check time at any ocean, this `currentTimeZone` returns null.
So in that case, I show the GMT value.

```
String time = null;
Integer timeZone = (int) (((longitude / 7.5) + 1) / 2);

if (timeZone >= 0) {
    time = "GMT+" + timeZone;
} else {
    time = "GMT" + timeZone;
}
```

So the `time` value will be of the kind GMT+somevalue. I want to find another solution for this case. In this case also I want to display the time value. How can I do that? Is there any way to get the GMT value? Note: I dont want to show the date only time is required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked. Code is given below:

```
Integer timeZone = (int) (((longitude / 7.5) + 1) / 2);
DateFormat dateformat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
dateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, timeZone);   //Adding/Subtracting hour to current date time
String newdate = dateformat.format(cal.getTime());
```